# MVC Установка Naudio.Lame

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

using Naudio нормально, а using Naudio.Lame ошибка. Оба установлены через NuGet

Ошибка:

в using Naudio.Lame - тип или имя пространство имен "Lame" не существует в пространстве имен "Naudio"

Comment: какая у вас ошибка?

Comment: Прощу прошения, Виталий! У меня это в Net Core 2.2